# Best practice about JavaScript Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

```
return makeFirstPromise()
    .then(function(res1) {
       (...)
    })
    .then(function(res2) {
       (...)
    })
    .then(function(res3) {
        // **here I need to access res1**
    });
```

I would like to know if there is a best practice when I need to access to a previous promise result in a subsequent function of my promise chain.

I see two possible solutions:

```
var r1;
return makeFirstPromise()
    .then(function(res1) {
       r1 = res1;
       (...)
    })
    .then(function(res2) {
       (...)
    })
    .then(function(res3) {
        console.log(r1);
    });
```

or to nest the promises following the first but it visually breaks the chain sequence:

```
return makeFirstPromise()
    .then(function(res1) {
       (...)
       return secondPromise(res2)
           .then(function(res3) {
               console.log(res1);
           });
    });
```

Any idea?

Comment: exact duplicate of [How do I access previous promise results in a .then() chain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250680/how-do-i-access-previous-promise-results-in-a-then-chain)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promise syntax is conceived to [be used in the first way](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/?redirect_from_locale=de#toc-chaining). The second syntax gets confusing very fast.
But don't forget to pass the result into the next promise.

```
var r1;
return makeFirstPromise()
    .then(function(res1) {
       r1 = res1;
       (...)
       return r1;
    })
    .then(function(r1) {
       (...)
    });
```

Comment: The problem is my second promise already returns a value (res2).

Comment: Make an array `[]` or object `{}` out of the results.

Comment: Could leads to a complicated code if I don't control the second promise (like a nodejs function) but I prefer this solution over the variable declaration solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually promises proxy values, the easiest way to use them with values is to use them as proxies. This is what they abstract:

```
var res1 = makeFirstPromise();
var res2 = res1.then(makeSecondPromise);
Promise.all([res1, res2]).spread(function(firstResult, secondResult){
    // access both here, no nesting or closure hacks required.
});
```

Comment: nice idea but I have a chain of promises and it could be the 7th that needs a result from the 3th promise, for instance.

Comment: Why would it matter? Also note that some promise implementations like Bluebird have a context you can pass around - look at Promise#bind at bluebird's API - that can also solve your problem.